# LMoP: what are some tips for replaying the Redbrand Hideout?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, published-adventures

[Spoilers, Lost Mine of Phandelver, D&D 5e] I'm DMing.

> The party barely failed to catch Glasstaff when they ran through the Redbrand Hideout. Now some time has passed in-game and IRL and they want to make another raid on the Redbrands to take out Glasstaff for real this time. So my first question is, if Glasstaff resumes his research, could he possibly manage to create potions of invisibility like he was wanting? Nothing in the module or online implies how close he is.

In spite of searching fruitlessly for examples of rerunning a map, I have found nothing, especially when it comes to the Lost Mine.

What are some good tips/advice for rerunning a scenario like this, taking these potential plot developments into account?

Edit: I've been taking some leaves from the Hello Neighbor book.

Comment: Hi Julian, welcome to StackRPG! This question is more of a solicitation for tips than seeking a definitive answer, and would be a better candidate to bring up in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) area. When you get a minute be sure to take the [tour]. Thanks for joining the site!

Answer (score 3):

Put yourself in the named person's position: what would you do?

If it were me I would either:

1. Abandon a hideout that had previously proved vulnerable, or
2. Substantially reinforce the hideout and add more and varied ways in which I could escape.

Either way, I would be much more proactive in f$)king with the bastards who just f@&ked with me. You are **not** going to catch me napping and if you aren't on your game I **am** going to catch you napping.

As for pursuing blue sky research- nope: I'm going to be out there enlisting allies to make the PCs dead, dead, dead.

D&D villains are not computer RPG villains who wait around to be killed.